# Need a bigger desktop, not a bigger monitor

Tags: desktop-environment

can't think how to ask this question, so apologise for the super long question.

I have a very low power machine, with a very tiny screen. The problem is the screen size, the computer is more than fine for the tasks.

I have been able to increase the resolution of the screen by overdriving it. I loose quality of image but that is ok. What I would like to do next is make the desktop larger. 1920x1080 sounds good, but I don't want to change the monitor from 1026x614. What I would prefer is the viewed area of my desktop to follow the mouse around. Does that make sense? If it does and you know what I am trying to do, even giving it a name so I can search how to do it on google helps. The OS I am using is Raspbian on a Raspberry pi 3

Regards
Monery

Comment: The term you're looking for is "virtual desktop". Search for that.

Comment: Lose is spelled l-o-s-e

Comment: it is. Missed that one ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set up a panning viewport with `xrandr`. E.g

```
$ xrandr --output eDP-1 --mode 1026x614 --panning 1920x1080
```

and be sure to replace `eDP-1` with whatever your monitor is called, and `1026x614` with whatever your display mode is called. A plain `xrandr` without arguments should tell you that.
Try also

```
$ man xrandr
```

for more details.

Comment: using this command generated the following error
xrandr --output default --mode 800x480 --panning 1920x1080
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: screen cannot be larger than 800x480 (desired size 1920x1080)

Comment: The `man` page suggests adding `--fb 1920x1080` as first argument. Did you try that already?